# Play Framework(2.2.4) deployment issue cannot find Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, playframework

I've created an application in Play an have deployed it to a linux server. 
The app was developed on win7 and I ran 'dist' and copied the zip file over to the server. 
I'm using DataTables (http://datatables.net/examples/styling/stripe.html) and TwitterBootstrap in the application but I can't seen any of this rendering in the app deployed to the server. I see it on my localmachine. Any idea why?

Comment: that is such a broad question, you need to give us more, contents of the dist folder, is the service up and running?

Comment: Running the 'dist' command generated a zip file in  {app_home}/target/universal/app.zip. This is the zip that was transferrd to the unix server..unzipping the file there's then a few other folders bin,conf,lib,logs,and share...